# erro em obter valores a partir array stdClass php

Tags: php, array, stdclass

Quando eu uso `echo var_dump($location);` eu obtenho isto:

```
object(stdClass)#1226 (2) { ["type"]=> string(5) "Point" ["coordinates"]=> array(2) { [0]=> float(44.0928438) [1]=> float(-70.20876942) } }
```

Eu tentei obter os numeros floats((44.0928438, -70.20876942)), com o seguinte código:

```
$lat = $location["type"]["coordinates"][0];
$long = $location["type"]["coordinates"][1];
```

Mas quando eu corro o meu ficheiro php, dá-me o seguinte erro não porque:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aw014/ExternalWebServiceAdapter/Adapters/TwitterAdapter.class.php
>   on line 62

Comment: Adicionalmente às respostas mais elaboradas, um *var_dump()* seguido de um *echo* não só é errado como desnecessária, haja vista que *var_dump()* já envia *output* para o browser. ^_^

Comment: Acho que o var_dump foi só pra mostrar o conteúdo do objeto como forma de debugging, não deve ser para exibir dado para o browser...

Comment: Coloque a `$location` no seu código ! se puder queria ver? Porque imagino se for uma classe tem que usar `->` !!! mas, antes preciso ver o `$location`

Comment: @Wakim, sim, sim, mas eu sou ranzinza, fazer o quê? :p

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, entendido, sem problemas hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ocorre que a sintaxe de colchetes até certo tempo atrás era uma exclusividade dos arrays.

Porém, pouco a pouco (relativamente falando) os Objetos foram sendo aprimorados. Primeiro eles puderam ser iterados tal qual um array normal. A consequência natural disso seria os objetos que representam um array também poderem adotar a sintaxe de colchetes.

Essa habilidade se dá por fazer um objeto implementar a interface [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) (e seus métodos). Ironicamente, parece que a classe [stdClass](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.classes.php) não recebeu essa implementação e, por isso, o **Fatal Error**.

Para solucionar o problema você tem duas opções:

1. Mapear esse Objeto stdClass num array:

   ```
   function map( $param ) {

       if( is_object( $param ) ) {
           $param = get_object_vars( $param );
       }

       if( is_array( $param ) ) {
           return array_map( __FUNCTION__, $param );
       }

       return $param;
   }
   ```

   É possível também forçar o *cast* desse objeto para array:

   ```
   $data = (array) $original;
   ```

   Mas isso não é recursivo. No seu caso não seria um problema pois você tem um único objeto [stdClass](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.classes.php), mas a função acima ainda vale como referência pois vai convertendo para array tantos [stdClass](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.classes.php) quantos ela encontrar, hierarquicamente falando.
2. Procurar alternativas para o resultado **não vir** numa [stdClass](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.classes.php)

   Pelo conteúdo das entradas desse objeto é notável que está havendo o consumo de uma API de GeoTargeting ou, pelo menos, um *fetching* dos dados do banco de dados usando objetos como *fetching style*

   No caso de uma API, normalmente os dados são trafegados em JSON que é um formato "universal". Para trabalhar com JSON com PHP você usa [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) com a **intenção** de produzir um array.

   Para o PHP, suas intenções quase sempre não valem nada. Por isso que, por padrão, [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) devolve os dados numa [stdClass](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.classes.php).

   No entanto, é simples de contornar isso. Basta passar o segundo argumento [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) como **TRUE**:

   ```
   $data = jsondecode( $original, TRUE );
   ```

   Caso os dados estejam sofrendo influência de um *fetching style* verifique a documentação da forma como você lê o recurso da consulta definindo que não sejam usados objetos.

   Na [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO), por exemplo, por padrão, um recurso é devolvido em arrays, tanto indexados quanto associativos ([PDO::FETCH_BOTH](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.constants.php)), mas é bastante comum de ser alterado para [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.constants.php) ou, no caso que talvez possa ser o seu, [PDO::FETCH_OBJ](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.constants.php)

Comment: Obrigado resolveu a minha questão

Comment: Mas qual foi o cenário que eu acertei? O do JSON ou o do banco de dados?